# How to detected truncated strings by the front end libraries?

Tags: automated-testing, web-application

Here's a site I've encountered.  Note that the "Welcome" string is truncated.  My screen isn't narrow at all: it's more than 1000px wide.
[image: Screenshot]

The Chrome browser's inspect tool says that the "Welcome" string isn't truncated at all. It's in a `<span>`:

```
<span>Welcome</span>
```

To test the potentially truncated strings like this, I cannot just query the DOM. What are the tools and libraries available in the software testing industry to catch such undesirable modifications by the front end library?

Comment: It *hasn't* been truncated by a front-end library, if you're seeing the whole word in the DOM, just by the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the text-overflow is not ellipsis with WebDriver/Selenium.

In Python:

```
assert element.value_of_css_property("text-overflow") != "ellipsis"
```

in Java:

```
element.getCssValue("text-overflow")
```

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetCssValue.htm

Comment: Thanks. I've confirmed that the css property "text-overflow" is applicable in my case.